# How to use ico-moon icon in an email html for different email client like outlook gmail

Tags: html, css, icons, html-email

Please let me know how to include ico-moon icons in an email html and should be render in email clients like outlook,gmail.

Comment: Hi! It looks like you're trying to ask a question. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Honestly, we have no idea what an ico-moon icon might look like without knowing which one you refer to in your question.

Answer (score 0):

any css code will not render in outlook desktop app I recommend you not to use ico-moon icons use images instead

Comment: Thanks for the reply right now  I am going ahead with using html entity codes.